# ajax call brings 404 Not Found error but code works

Tags: php, jquery

```
$(".click").click(function(){   
    var request = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "post.php",
        data: {file: "123"}         
    });         
});
```

When this code worked, firebug brings this error `"404 Not Found"` on `post.php`, but in any case the code in `post.php` works successfully.

What is the reason of this behavior, and how can I fix it.

Comment: Where does your php file located? give the folder structure

Comment: need to get response from url file like true/false to make code flow correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try by specifying full url inplace of post.php.

Answer (score 0):

Path is wrong `url: "post.php",` Give proper path relative to from where you are executing AJAX.

Comment: @RabNawaz : coz it is showing 404 => see question `"firebug brings this error "404 Not Found" on post.php, but in any case the code in post.php works successfully."`

Answer (score 0):

This is why because of success handler not working. can you check with complete handler. If no problem with complete handler overwrite the 404 that something sends on the server by executing (before printing any output): header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK'). Since the script is executed, this will overwrite the crazy 404 and jQuery will receive that 200 and execute the success handler.